# Перезапуск линукс по расписанию

Tags: bash, скрипт

как написать скрипт для каждодневной перезагрузки дебиана в 4:00, причем из ждущего режима , и дальнейшем уходом в ждущий режим.
Если это возможно сделать.По моим соображениям компьютер работающий постоянно ,нужно перезагружать для обновления, или может я что-то не так понимаю?

То есть вывести пк в 4:00 из ждущего режима-->перезагрузить-->выполнить update/upgrade-->вернуться в ждущий режим.
Спасибо.

Comment: не нужно ничего перезагружать. Линукс нужно перезагружать если обновилось ядро и еще в каких-нибудь редких случаях. А так он может годами прекрасно работать без перезагрузок

Comment: Тут наверное стоило бы пояснить, идет ли речь о каком-то персональном / тестовом компьютере или о компьютере организации / сервере.

Comment: как вы себе представляете перезагрузку из ждущего режима? для вывода из ждущего придётся использовать внешнее устройство какое-то. Вообще сомнительный профит делать перезагрузку в ждущем режиме - так как цель ждущего режима обычно сохранить состояние компа.

Comment: @xmikex Пробуждение по расписанию не требует какого-то внешнего устройства.

Comment: ну расскажите про пробуждение по расписанию в общем случае, когда в биос подобных опций нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик *"Линукс нужно перезагружать если обновилось ядро и еще в каких-нибудь редких случаях."* - как раз наоборот, линукс приходится перезагружать при абсолютно любом обновлении, так как иначе из-за отсутствия блокировки файлов будет возникать ситуация, когда в части процессов используются одна версия какого-то файла, а в другом - другая.

Comment: @xmikex пробуждение по расписанию не требует никаких манипуляций с биос

Comment: @user7860670 неделями не перегружал и никаких таких ситуаций не возникало

Comment: @Эникейщик Видимо у вас [Систематическая ошибка выжившего](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE) и упомянутые ситуации вы даже не искали, что кстати является нетривиальным занятием, если они не приводят сразу к каким-то тяжелым последствиям.

Comment: @user7860670 зачем же мне искать какие-то редкие гипотетические проблемы, которые к тому же легко решаются перезапуском программы, если вдруг что.

Comment: @Эникейщик Эта проблема не редкая и не гипотетическая. *"легко решаются перезапуском программы"* - ну видимо Систематическая ошибка выжившего в вас очень сильна. ¿Как вообще можете говорить об устранении последствий таких ситуаций, если у вас не было такого опыта и вы в них даже не попадали? А я вот могу сказать, что разгребание последствий может растянутся на месяцы и чревато серьезными материальными потерями. Собственно я специально в своем первом комментарии акцентировал внимание, на том, идет ли речь о каком-то важном кстройстве.

Comment: @user7860670 да из вопросе же видно, что ни о каком важном устройстве тут речи и быть не может :)

Comment: @user7860670 присоединюсь к «выжившим», у меня подобных проблем тоже не возникало, мои сервера на Ubuntu работают стабильно годами

Comment: В современной архитектуре бекенда обычно соблюдается идея "один инстанс ОС = один сервис (да еще и в контейнере)", следовательно, чтобы все обновилось, достаточно сделать этому сервису рестарт. Ну и для ядра тоже есть решение.

Таким образом, проблема, указанная @user7860670 может возникать в довольно редких стечениях обстоятельств (собственно, борьба с ней и привела к идее "инстанс ОС = сервис")

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно установить и настроить [Unattended Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)

`apt` выполняет свои задачи по двум расписаниям `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer` и `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer`

В `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer` по умолчанию написано

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6,18:00
RandomizedDelaySec=12h
```

Из-за `RandomizedDelaySec=12h` он запускается в произвольное время дважды в сутки, что бесит. Вам нужно указать `OnCalendar=*-*-* 4:00` и удалить `RandomizedDelaySec`. Каждый день в 4:00 apt будет проверять наличие обновлений и скачивать новые пакеты.

В `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer` по умолчанию задано

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6:00
RandomizedDelaySec=60m
```

Каждый день в 6 утра apt устанавливает новые пакеты. Вы можете поставить тоже `OnCalendar=*-*-* 4:00` - тогда в 4 утра после завершения скачивания будет запускаться установка обновленных пакетов. То, что установка будет после скачивания, гарантируется строкой `After=apt-daily.timer`.

Если после обновления потребуется перезагрузка, `UnattendedUpgrades` самостоятельно перезагрузит.

Comment: кнопкой "править" можно внести изменения в ответ. Тогда не придется удалять.

Comment: Сорри, рука дрогнула и получился второй ответ.

Comment: PS. Я лично считаю автоматические обновления извращением на грани мазохизма. И первым делом на своих новых убунтах отключаю.

Comment: Pak Uula спасибо за ответ, плюсануть пока не могу только зарегился.